# How to make jquery rotate works in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-rotate

I tried to make jquery rotate works in IE8.In all browsers it is working except IE8.How can i get it for IE8.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   function rotation(){
      $(".stand").rotate({ 
         angle:0,
        animateTo:-15,
        duration:6000,
        center: ["50%", "100%"],
        easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo
        });
     }
     $("#one").click(function(){
        rotation();
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Add your html structure please

Comment: Please add your complete code.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever jQuery plugin you're using here, it looks like it's using CSS3 transforms, which [are not supported by IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

There is a [polyfill](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/) available called [CSS Sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/) that claims to support IE6 and above, but I've never used it so I don't know if it's any good, and I don't know if it would work with your jQuery rotation plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, you are using the latest version of jQuery rotate? There are known issues with that version in case you are trying to rotate div's instead of images.

Use this version:

[jQuery Rotate 3.1](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/source/browse/trunk/jQueryRotate3.js?r=120)

It works for me like a charm. But be careful - if you want to use your app for iOS it might let your app crash because of a known memory leak caused by css3 transitions. No problems on desktop tho..

Comment: jQueryRotate3.js i am using

Comment: add your html markup to your post and let me know which jquery version you are using.